# Read in Student info from a .txt file and then caluclate the average and find the letter grade

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector, struct

Im working on this program to read in students first, last name, and 5 grades and put the students info into a struct. From there Im trying to use other functions to find the average grade, letter grade, max grade, and minimum grade. Im having issues on the proper way to read in and store students info and then call upon students info within other functions to calculate average, letter grade, etc... My 'displayAverages' function doesn't list any names and the grades are huge negative numbers. IF you can help me (after your headache from looking at my code goes away that is) Id appreciate it.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath> 
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// Global variables
const int MAX_STUDENTS = 22;
const int MAX_GRADES = 5;
const string FILENAME = "NamesGrades.txt";

struct Student{
    string name;
    double grades[MAX_GRADES];
    double average;
    int max;
    int min;
}students[MAX_STUDENTS];
char getLetterGrade(double grade);

void getData(Student &students)
{
    ifstream fileIn;
    int numStudents = 0;

    fileIn.open(FILENAME.c_str());
    if (fileIn.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fileIn) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; i++)
        {
            Student students;
            getline(fileIn, students.name);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_GRADES; i++)
            {
                fileIn >> students.grades[i];
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    fileIn.close();

    return;
}



void displayAverages(Student students) {
    double total;
    //double average;
    int maxLength = 50;

    cout << setprecision(1) << fixed << showpoint;

    // Providing a header
    cout << "\n\nGrade Averages\n";
    cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << "Name" << setw(4) << right <<

        "Average" << setw(6) << "Grade" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << students.name;
        total = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
        {
            total += students.grades[i];
        }

        students.average = (double)total / MAX_GRADES;

        cout << setw(7) << right << students.average << setw(6) <<

            getLetterGrade(students.average) << endl;
    }
}


char getLetterGrade(double grade) {
        {
        if (grade > 90) {
            return 'A';
        }
        else if (grade > 80) {
            return 'B';
        }
        else if (grade > 70) {
            return 'C';
        }
        else if (grade > 60) {
            return 'D';
        }
        else {
            return 'F';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the format of the file?

Comment: Please see: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This isn't just a requirement for asking questions on here, its' also a valuable part of learning to debug your own code

Comment: Please search the internet before posting.  There are already a plethora of student grade assignments on StackOverflow.  Search for "C++ student grade assignment".  Otherwise, use a debugger.

Comment: Can we get the input file. Or at least the first two students.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your `getData()` function. It's defined as:

```
void getData(Student &students)
```

Since the return type is `void`, I'm guessing that you'll probably be passing in a `Student` and then modifying it in the function. However, you do:

```
Student students;
getline(fileIn, students.name);
```

Uh oh! This declares a new `students` that shadows the parameter `students`. So when you do `students.name`, you're talking about the local variable, not the parameter.

Kill that new declaration and things should work like you expected!

Answer (score -1):

First thing - your code should have better structure!

```
void getData(Student &students)
{
    ifstream fileIn;
    int numStudents = 0;// you are not using this variable

    fileIn.open(FILENAME.c_str());
    if (fileIn.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fileIn) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; i++)//you should use auto here
        {
            Student students;//here you are making local object instead of changing the data off passed argument, you should get rid of this
            getline(fileIn, students.name);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_GRADES; i++)//you should use auto here
            {
                fileIn >> students.grades[i];
            }
            return;//you will return from you function after reading first student data so you should get rid of this
        }
    }
    fileIn.close();
    return;
}
```

After changes:

```
void getData(Student &students) {
    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open(FILENAME.c_str());
    if(fileIn.fail()) {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fileIn) {
        for(auto i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; i++) {
            getline(fileIn, students.name);
            for(auto i = 0; i < MAX_GRADES; i++)
                fileIn >> students.grades[i];
        }
    }
    fileIn.close();
}
```